# How to read and write local file using angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, filesystems, angular2-routing, angular5

In angular 2, is there any way to read/write files from absolute path?
I have used '**filesaver**' library to save the file, where I save the file
locally in txt/json format.
Example :

```
let blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportFile').innerHTML],{ 
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
});
saveAs(blob, "export.json");
```

Now I want to read and write/edit export.json file. How can I refer it for the next time?
Is there any other way or is there any good library available for these
operations?

Comment: Why are you saving the file under json format ?

Comment: Requirement is, I should save the admin dashboard layout data in some file. Where the widgets are movable, after widgets change there position I need to store the widgets css in some object and inturn storing that in json file. when user visits again he should get his modified layout. Basically I was asked to implement it locally by storing the data in some file. If you have better approach for this please help

Answer (score 1):

To read your file you can do this (using HttpClient)

```
public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
         return this.http.get("./export.json")
                         .map(res => {var data = res.json(); return data});

}
```

Unfortunately you cannot use put / post to write into the file, but I can recommend you 'jsonfile' library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile

Hope it will help you!

Comment: I am unable to use this library, how to import this?

Comment: Npm install —save jsonfile

Comment: Then use require statement to import in your code jsonfile