# How to send form data as file to server- Angular

Tags: angular, filesystems

I have a schema-form, Once the user fills in the form, I have to save the form data into file as an xml and send it to server. Is it possible to save the form data to a file.

Comment: No angular cannot write to a file. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288087/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-a-locally-json-file-with-nothing-but-angular

Comment: You can't send the xml to the server and save it as a file there?

Comment: Editing file in front-end angular is bad thing to do anyway we can't do it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393628/how-to-read-and-write-local-file-using-angular-2)... post form object to backend and writing on server side would be preferable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393628/how-to-read-and-write-local-file-using-angular-2